# How can I use the enableSweep() function in ERC20?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

```
function enableSweep(uint8[] _vs, bytes32[] _rs, bytes32[] _ss, address _to) public onlySweeper.
```

I don't know how to get the parameters of `_vs`, `_rs` and `_ss`.

Comment: Your question does not seem related to ERC20. According to [its interface](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard), enableSweep is not an ERC20 function.

Comment: GUSD（Gemini dollar）is also the ERC20,The notes of this function is /** param  _vs  The array of recovery byte components of the ECDSA signatures.
      * param  _rs  The array of 'R' components of the ECDSA signatures.
      * param  _ss  The array of 'S' components of the ECDSA signatures.
      * param  _to  The destination for swept balances.
      */.How can I get the params of _rs _ss _vs